# Creating WCF for Windows Phone

Tags: wcf, binding, windows-phone

## Help creating WCF for Windows Phone

I need some massive help in being pointed in the right Direction.
I created a pretty extensive Windows Phone app based upon my own WCF + SQLAzure + Windows phone.

Problem is that I am using **WCF-basicHTTPBinding** and now want to take advantage of other advanced features(such as GZip compression, JSON headers and Azure ACS).  This means I will need to move from basicHTTPBinding to either a **REST solution(webHTTPBindign)** or **wsHTTPBinding**

However wsHTTBindingand webHTTPBinding are either *not supported*, impossible, or not recommended by the MS - Documentation i have read.

I have pured over all documentation and it does not appear there is a **known path developers to write a basic Web Service and expose it to the Windows Phone using Microsoft Technologies other than the old school ASMX webservices(WCF-basicHTTPBinding).**

Every article i have seen making a case for OData has not touched WCF bindings... which leads me to believe they are also doing a basicHTTPBinding even though it is OData.

### Please Help

I beg somone to make some sense out of which direction I should go?
It just seems very fustraiting there would be no "here is your good path" appraoch to this.

**Goals:**
Windows Phone + WCF that includes a solution I can use GZip and JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post on Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2010/WPH306) tells all about making occasionally connected applications using JSON and rest. His application uses POCOs so it's very easy to scale up to use EF or something else if you want. It's an hour long video, but it's a good place to get started

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a JSON payload then you will have to use webHttpBinding. This allows HTTP based services that are not SOAP. From windows phone you can then use the HTTP client that you have available (not sure if that's WebClient or WebRequest).

You will get the HTTP response and you can unzip it and process the JSON yourself from there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do WCF REST...move to the new ASP.NET Web APIs found in the ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta. They have moved from the WCF umbrella to ASP.NET MVC:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx